# SQL script stops compiling after reaching first trigger END

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Every time I try to run my database script I reach the last few lines that have my 2 triggers and my script stops after compiling the first trigger.

These are the 2 triggers I have and it compiles "Player Round Trigger" and then the script stops and doesn't reach my second trigger "Handicap Trigger"

```
--
-- Player Round Trigger
--
CREATE TRIGGER playerRoundUpdateAudit BEFORE UPDATE ON PlayerRound
  FOR EACH row BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PlayerRoundAudit(old_data_PlayerID, old_data_RoundID, old_data_Holenumber, old_data_holeScore,
    new_data_PlayerID, new_data_RoundID, new_data_Holenumber, new_data_holeScore, tbl_name) 
    VALUES (OLD.playerID, OLD.roundID, OLD.holeNumber, OLD.holeScore, NEW.playerID, NEW.roundID, NEW.holeNumber, NEW.holeScore, "PlayerRound");
END;
/


--
-- Handicap Trigger
--
CREATE TRIGGER handicapUpdateAudit BEFORE UPDATE ON Handicap
  FOR EACH row BEGIN
    INSERT INTO HandicapAudit(old_data_handicapID, old_data_playerID, old_data_handicapDate, old_data_handicapScore,
    new_data_handicapID, new_data_playerID, new_data_handicapDate, new_data_handicapScore, tbl_name) 
    VALUES (OLD.handicapID, OLD.playerID, OLD.handicapDate, OLD.handicapScore, NEW.handicapID, NEW.playerID, NEW.handicapDate, NEW.handicapScore, "Handicap");
END;
/
```

I'm running the script in Oracle SQL Developer  version 4.1.2.20 (the newest one atm)

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is no error. The script just finishes after compiling the first trigger with no errors. It doesnt reach the second trigger.

Comment: How did you run it? F5?

Comment: @hinotf Yes, I ran it using F5.

Comment: @Recap so strange, but why OLD instead of :OLD?

Comment: @hinotf I was following a tutorial and it works the way i need it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acturlly the first triggers compiles with errors, and breaks the script.

You can do an experiment - change a header of first trigger into `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ....`, 
then in SQL Developer click on the first trigger to move cursor into it's code, then press Ctrl-Enter - this executes one statement where the cursor is placed (actually - 'CREATE` statement of the first trigger).

Then examine "Compiler log" window - you will see a message like this:
[image]

There are two problems with this trigger:

- you are using `OLD.column_name` and `NEW.column_name`, what is wrong. You need use `:OLD.column_name` and `:NEW.column_name`, using a colon as a prefix
- you are using double quotes instead of quotes here: `"PlayerRound"`, and Oracle doesn't interpret this as a string, but as an identifier (of variable, column name etc.). Use `'PlayerRound'` within quotes instead.

---

Change the first trigger like below an it should compile:

```
set define off
CREATE or replace TRIGGER playerRoundUpdateAudit BEFORE UPDATE ON PlayerRound
      FOR EACH row BEGIN
        INSERT INTO PlayerRoundAudit(old_data_PlayerID, old_data_RoundID,
                    old_data_Holenumber, old_data_holeScore,
                    new_data_PlayerID, new_data_RoundID, new_data_Holenumber, 
                    new_data_holeScore, tbl_name) 
        VALUES (:OLD.playerID, :OLD.roundID, :OLD.holeNumber, :OLD.holeScore, 
              :NEW.playerID, :NEW.roundID, :NEW.holeNumber, :NEW.holeScore, 'PlayerRound');
end;
/
```

You need also correct the second trigger, because it contains similar errors.

---

Remark : put `SET DEFINE OFF` into the script to turn off a variable substitution, otherwise SQL-Developer will prompt to enter a value for each `:NEW` and `:OLD`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with Oracle SQL Developer but is there an option to run the script as "Execute as script"? This feature is available on TOAD...